# PHP Temporary File Does Not Exist

Tags: php, wordpress, upload

I'm working on a Wordpress plugin that has its own file upload form to import data.  I have a really basic form upload script.  I want to keep the files in the temporary directory, I won't be storing the uploaded files permanently.

Here is the upload script:

```
<?php
echo $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
```

I get a temporary location, but the file does not exist on my file system.  I'm on Fedora 21.

The HTML form looks like this:

```
<form action=<?php echo plugins_url() . '/upload.php'; ?> method='post' enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <h4>Data Import</h4>
    <fieldset>
        File: <input type='file' title='spreadsheet' name='file'><br>
        <input type='submit' name='Import' value='Import'>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
$uploaddir = './temporaryfolder/'; //give this dir write permissions
$uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['file']['name']);


if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
    //now you can get the filename
    $file = basename($uploadfile);
    echo "File <b>$file</b> is valid, and was successfully uploaded.\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is called temporary location, because files exist there only temporary. You have to relocate them somewhere else to  be able to "fetch" them.

However you mentioned you don't want to keep those files - therefore I suggest you to write yourself an algorithm that will take care of files after you don't need them anymore. May be based on age of the file or something else, you decide.

How to relocate those files after upload is mentioned in Pedro Lobito's answer.